# Error al graficar voltajes y corrientes con sympy

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer un código graficar voltajes y corrientes en corriente alterna y tira error.

Este es el código:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import symbols
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
V=float(input("ingrese la tension maxima: "))
R=float(input("ingrese la resistencia: "))
F=float(input("ingrese la frecuencia: "))
w=2*pi*F
t=np.linspace(-10,10)
vr=(V*sin(w*t))
i=(V/R)*sin(w*t)
plt.figure("corriente y voltaje")
plt.title("tension en resistencia")
plt.plot(t,Vr,'r')
plt.xlabel("wt")
plt.ylabel("ir, vr")
plt.plot(t,i,'g')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
V=float(input("ingrese la tension maxima: "))
R=float (input ("ingrese la resistencia: "))
F=float(input("ingrese la frecuencia: "))
w=2*np.pi*F
t=np.linspace(-10,10)
vr=(V*np.sin(w*t))
i=(V/R)*np.sin(w*t)
plt.title("tension en resistencia")
plt.plot(t,vr,'r')
plt.xlabel("wt")
plt.ylabel("ir, vr")
plt.plot(t,i,'g')
plt.show()
```

Estas haciendo uso incorecto del módulo sympy, que esta destinado para operciones de matemática simbólica. Tu problema puede resolverse solo utilizando numpy.